# How do I select QtCurve theme for GTK apps in KDE?

Tags: kde, gtk, themes

I have only the base KDE installed (`sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop`), not the entire `kubuntu-desktop`. Unfortunately GTK apps have the fugly Raleigh theme. I've installed QtCurve with `sudo apt-get install qtcurve`, but the GTK apps still have Raleigh theme. I assume I have to select the QtCurve theme somehow.

---

@13east has posted a picture of the settings dialog in his answer below. Unfortunately the GTK+ appearance is the only tab that is **missing** from my Settings Dialog. I assume this is because I've installed only plasma-desktop instead of the entire kubuntu-desktop. Is there a way to manually set the theme, perhaps by editing some configuration files?

Comment: If you've added the kubuntu-desktop from w/in an gnome installation, I'd recommend doing a fresh installation of Kubuntu on your machine if you can spare the time and have your data backed up to do so.  It will be better for you if you have a clean install on you machine instead of having a hybrid-mix of gnome/gtk and kde/qt dependencies, as it will bring you a lot more problems like this in the future.

Comment: IIRC there's some package named `kde-gtk`  , which is why you don't have the GTK config tab

Answer (score 1):

If you open the "System Settings" app, there's an icon in the top row for something like "application settings" (I think it's second or third from the left in the top row--I don't have KDE available at the moment). If you click on that icon you'll see a dialogue with a few options in the left-hand panel. One of them is to set the theme for GTK applications. You should just be able to select qtcurve from the drop-down menu in the right-hand pane under that tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. This tab is missing. See above, I've edited my question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC there's some package named `kde-gtk`  , which is why you don't have the GTK config tab.

Also , you should edit `~/.gtkrc-2.0` manually if things above failed to function:

`include "/usr/share/themes/QtCurve/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"`

For GTK3 , i'm not sure if it's supported.

Comment: The package is called kde-config-gtk-style.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings -> Application Appearance -> GTK+ Appearance -> Widget Style

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. This tab is missing. See above, I've edited my question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Install the kde-config-gtk package, and you'll get the missing sub-applet. OTOH, trying to use this still doesn't change the GTK theme, but I'm using 12.04 beta 1.